# Beautiful soup question, for loop problem

Tags: django, beautifulsoup

#Well this is my code and i have no idea why doesnt it show more results on the page, its grabs the price, link, title but shows 1 result, ident is ok, no erros, tried all the containers from find all , still one result, can you please advise me the mistake.Benn through this for a week

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.shortcuts import render
from urllib.parse import quote_plus #adding plus sign in search
from . import models

BASE_URL = 'https://www.olx.ua/list/q-{}'


def home(request):
    return render(request,'base.html')
def new_search(request):
    search=request.POST.get('search') #pull data out of search bar # that post request we are fetching
    #search model gives to searches to database
    models.Search.objects.create(search=search) #model creating search object with search argument is search and feeds to search request
    final_url = BASE_URL.format(quote_plus(search)) #
    response = requests.get(final_url)
    data= response.text #spit out text
    soup= BeautifulSoup(data, features='html.parser')


    final_postings= []

    post_listings = soup.find_all("div", class_="rel listHandler") 


    for post in post_listings: #looping through each post and show text
        post_titles = post.find('a',class_= ['marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink',
                                         'marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink 
                                          linkWithHashPromoted',
                                        ]).text
        post_url = post.find('a',class_= ['marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink',
                                          'marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink 
                                          linkWithHashPromoted']).get('href')


        if post.find('div',class_= 'space inlblk rel'):
            post_price = post.find('div',class_= 'space inlblk rel').text
        else:
            post_price= 'N/A'

        if post.find('img',class_='fleft').get('src'):
            post_image= post.find(class_='fleft').get('src')

        else:
            post_image= 'https://cutt.ly/FnA2cK7'


        final_postings.append((post_titles,post_url,post_price,post_image)) 

    stuff_for_frontend = {'search':search, 'final_postings':final_postings,}
    return render(request, 'my_app/new_search.html',stuff_for_frontend)
```

#html page
{%extends 'base.html'%}

```
{%block content%}

<h2 style="text-align:center"> {{search | title}}  </h2> <
<div class="row"><!-- makes cards below go in a raw-->
   {%for post in final_postings %}

   <div class="col s4"><!-- 
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-image">
            <a href="{{ post.1 }}"><img src="{{ post.3 }}" alt=""></a>
         </div>
         <div class="card-content">
            <p>{{ post.0 }}</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
            <a href="{{post.1}}">Price : {{ post.2 }}</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>

   {%endfor%}

{%endblock content%}
```

Comment: Did you try this site scraping as a stand alone program rather than using it in Django ?

Comment: If you give us an example of `final_url` then we can try running this ourselves without the Django stuff. see https://replit.com/@LukeStorry/67953633 where I'm trying to get it running

Comment: @LukeStorry sorry , may be i got confused, final_url is a base url that is formated to do the search through couple of words, when it searched the list that is given to him without criterias it print all the results on the page, so scraper doesnt have a problem or limiter, but when it comes to getting a title, it out puts only 1(or grabs only one), tried different containers and divs from the page, nothing workds, gets the price, title and link right but, something is stoping it from continuing doing the search